# How to call a superclass method on a subclass object?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

I have a `MySuperClass`, `MySubClass` and `Main` classes

**MySuperClass.java**

```
public abstract MySuperClass { 
    String param; 

    public String getParam() { 
        return param;                  
    } 
}
```

**MySubClass.java**

```
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass { 
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public <T extends MySuperClass> void doWork (Class <T> subClassObject) { 
    subClassObject.getParam(); // method undefined 
}
```

Why? I specified `T extends MySuperClass` . So all `MySuperClass` method should work for the subclass. How to call a superclass's method from a subclass object?

Comment: Do you want the parameter to be a `Class<T>` or a `T`? Those are very different things.

Comment: You are confusing a Class with an instance of that class. You can only call the method for a `Class` on `Class`

Comment: I just tried `T` and it worked. I don't know the difference between <Class> T and T`

Comment: `Class<T>` is a `Class` object which represents the class of the object. `T` is an instance of class `T` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subClassObject` is not a `MySuperClass` instance, it's a [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance. You should define this parameter as `T`, not as `Class<T>` to get the behavior you want:

```
public <T extends MySuperClass> void doWork (T subClassObject) {
   subClassObject.getParam();
   // etc...
}
```

Comment: The generics is actually unnecessary and the OP should just declare the method as `public void doWork (MySuperClass subClassObject)`

Comment: @newacct wow, completely misread that for some reason. Tunnel vision of sorts ;-) I'll remove my misleading comment.